# Python use virtualenv to prevent library version conflicts. How ruby does it?

Tags: python, ruby, rubygems, pip, virtualenv

As title, python use `virtualenv` to isolate pip libraries for each python application. Ruby has gem, how does it prevent library version conflicts without a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundler` is generally used to lock dependency versions for a project (e.g. the gem versions). `rbenv` and `rvm` (there are several others too) are two common approaches to managing multiple versions of Ruby. A feature these provide (at least `rvm` does) is gemsets: these are a way to isolate your gem directories (so you may have a `default` gemset and a `edge` gemset or something; I don't find these very useful so I apologize for the bad examples).

In general `bundler` is usually seen as the "good enough" solution to isolating dependencies and gemsets don't seem to be used all that often anymore.